# Power saving script in Ubuntu

Tags: suspend

Their should be script which invoke when laptop runs in battery power. It change the cpu-frequency, usb_suspense etc.

Which script is done this job in Ubuntu? I need to change power saving strategy. Every time Ubuntu suspense USB device when run in battery power.

For that I have to run command manually to off the USB suspense.

Comment: If you have an nvidia card you can install a script to manually control your video card usage to save battery power http://pranavk.github.com/linux/power-saving-and-increasing-battery-backup-in-linux/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[as suggested by Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower)
and

[Power Management Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement)

Measure power consumption with powertop

Before you start making any changes, it is a good idea to first get a base line for what your current power consumption is:

```
sudo aptitude install powertop
sudo powertop
```

You must be running on battery power for powertop to get the machine's current watt usage.

Using less power with pm-powersave

The pm-utils package comes with scripts for managing low-power modes.

```
sudo aptitude install pm-utils
```

In order to enter low power mode, run this:

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

In order to leave low power mode, run this:

```
sudo pm-powersave false
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Your information is helpful. I want to know that, how ubuntu detect that laptop is now running in battery power? and what are the steps she takes to save power?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerManagement - look at the diagram